# Check the minimum pixel-value in a Raster using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'd like to check some basic statistic of a raster in my database. How can I determine the smallest raster value found in all raster tiles (enroaching all `srid`'s)? My code looks like:

```
SELECT min(ST_Value(rast)) as min, max(ST_Value(rast)) as max FROM <rastername>
```

Throws out: `function st_value(raster) does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own, here we go:

```
SELECT min((stats).min)
    FROM (SELECT ST_SummaryStats(rast, TRUE) 
       AS stats FROM <rastername>) foo;
```